# python библиотеки для перевода текста

Tags: python, поиск-библиотек, перевод

Учу питон, сейчас в процессе выполнения небольшого проекта. Нужна библиотека для перевода текста на китайский язык. Качество перевода не очень важно, но скорость перевода - да. Весь день сидел и искал что то подходящее, советуют **translate** либо **googletrans**. Первый не работает, а второй выдает ошибку. Прошу, господа, подкиньте что нибудь дельное.
Кому интересно, то при попытке работы с googletrans вылезала эта ошибка (translate вообще не переводит):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\змеюки\sqs_trnslt\qvst.py", line 6, in <module>
    translation = translator.translate(rus_spch, dest="zh-cn")
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\питон\Lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 182, in 
translate
    data = self._translate(text, dest, src, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\питон\Lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 78, in _translate
    token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\питон\Lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 194, in 
do
    self._update()
  File "D:\питон\Lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 62, in _update
    code = self.RE_TKK.search(r.text).group(1).replace('var ', '')      
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: Как вариант, купить платный API например от Яндекса и забыть про проблемы. Цены у них довольно божеские, примерно 50р за 100тыс. символов.

Comment: Mtranslate еще есть, но я ее не тестировал. Китайский язык вроде тоже поддерживается. https://pypi.org/project/mtranslate/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, web интерфейс и Яндекс и Гугл и Alibaba translator позволяют принимать на вход Excel таблицы до нескольких тысяч. Во-вторых, можно попробовать https://huggingface.co/joefox/mbart-large-ru-zh-ru-many-to-many-mmt, медленная (7.6 запросов в секунду примерно) но работает независимо, если есть gpu по идее заведется быстрее + можно попробовать переводить вот таким пайплайном zh -> en -> ru (1 запрос в секунду примерно), на huggingface можно найти все эти модели.

Answer (score 0):

```
from translate import Translator
translator= Translator(from_lang="russian", to_lang="chinese")
translation = translator.translate("your text")
print(translation)
```

Вот такой программный код работает, ещё надо скачать библиотеку, если этого не сделали

```
pip install translate
```

Информация взята была с этого сайта: https://coderlessons.com/tutorials/python-technologies/izuchite-obrabotku-teksta-na-python/python-perevod-teksta